# How to populate an iOS screen data

Tags: ios

It's rather a general question, but I think it is relevant and didn't found a good answer online.

In almost every screen, I have data I query the server and populate it in the screen (mostly in labels, text fields etc.)
Assume the server access takes "too much time" (even a 1 sec is noticable by the user)
I have a couple of options to do this, most of them I don't like:

1. Make the server call in `ViewDidLoad` - causes the loading of the screen to "hang".
2. Make the server call in the previous screen and use `MBProgressHUD` - breaks data encapsulation
3. Make the server call in `ViewDidAppear` - but then I need to have initial values in all the screen elements and the user will "see" me replacing them
4. do a `[HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(load_initial_data) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES]` on `ViewDidLoad` - doesn't solve the problem of solution 3

Any best practices regarding this one?

Comment: `Make the server call in ViewDidLoad - causes the loading of the screen to "hang".` If it hangs you're fefching the data synchronously and that is bad ;) Fetch it asynchronously.

Comment: @HAS - but then I'm practically in the same situation as solution 3

Comment: Yes, as Tander tells you in his answer you *must* provide some kind of loading indicator. How that might look like is totally up to you. There are way to many possibilities to list them here.

Answer (score 1):

You're right - that question is somewhat a little general. However I will try answer as best as I can.

Currently I do something similar with my app. I make server calls is almost every screen the user visits. However I don't take the approach you're trying to do. I break up the job of server calls over a few classes to split responsibility.

When I load a new `ViewController` onto the screen I hide all views that need data. So, for example, a `UITableView` is hidden when the view first loads. I then make the web service call - show the user a UILabel that just says "Loading..." (Obviously make it look nice with other UI elements )  - when the web service call is done, I am notified and I then prepare the data for display. Once I am done, I then show the UITableView already populated with data.

This approach has worked well so far for me.

Comment: so basically, you are doing solution 3 but with hidden elements instead of 0's and default values... hmm...

Comment: Yes, solution 3. Just hide UI elements that have no data at that point. When your web service call returns with a success - unhide the UI views that should at that point have data in them. Also the call to the WS in on the background thread - so UI doesn't lock up either.

Comment: thanks... I'm not sure if I like the user to wait (with waitIndicator) in the previous screen and see the screen perfectly, or pop the data when it's ready like you suggested... anyway - good solution, I'm keeping it open to motivate ppl to answer - but you'll get you r green V :)

Comment: I'm interested in a different approach if there is a better one too. I just don't see how. We need to take into account that not all users will be on super fast WiFi networks. So, what do you do in those cases? My solution means the user goes to screen 1 - I then call the web service with data I need for that screen. The user will see static UI elements that don't need to be loaded with dynamic data. If that screen had a UITableView that needed data I will just hide it and indicate that I am busy loading more data to the user. Once I have that data I show it to the user.

Comment: well... in this case - you are correct. BTW - in this specific case it is a profile screen so I divided the WS calls to "basic information" to present immediately (and this I fetch in screen N-1) and if I have a tableview - this is done afterwards...

Comment: So if you're calling the WS BEFORE you load the screen - why don't you "grab" its response in the next screen and not do any sort of waiting on the first screen?

Comment: that's exactly what I meant... not sure I like this solution. It breaks data encapsulation and the user waits without any visual cahnges

Comment: Why do you need start the WS one screen early? Why not make both WS calls in the next screen. There will always be a wait to the user depending on their internet speed and the amount of data that needs downloading. That is a limitation you're unable to control. You can just make the experience better. The best way is to let the user know there is a download task happening.

Comment: What Tander says is totally right. You said "one second" but that time changes when conditions change and in such a sensitive environment like mobile internet connections you cannot (I.e. you **must not**) assume that data will be there before it times out.